# Cross platform equivalent to XDialog

Tags: python, dialog, cross-platform

Is there a cross platform (OSX/Linux/Windows) tool similar in spirit to XDialog, that allows for a script in e.g. python, to prompt the user for input e.g. to answer a yes / no question, or to bring up a file selection dialog? A graphical prompt is preferable.

So far, I don't have a better approach than to write functions providing a uniform, cross platform API over a range of platforms, selecting the set of function implementations by testing for the specific platform in use.

I am currently using or intend to use:

- [EasyDialogs](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/EasyDialogs/) for Windows and older OSX (via Carbon)
- [CocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/) for OSX
- [wxCocoaDialog](http://code.google.com/p/wxcocoadialog/) for platforms with wxWidgets, including Windows

with a fall back to printing to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Most Python distributions come with [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) and convenience modules like `tkMessageBox` and `tkSimpleDialog`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox, tkSimpleDialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
if tkMessageBox.askYesNo('Hello', 'May I ask a question?'):
    name = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Query', 'Who are you?')
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Response', 'You are %s.' % (name,))
else:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Goodbye', 'Fine then.')
```

PyGTK, PyQt, PySide, and wxPython are also cross-platform.